# Boto3 TypeError: get_metric_data() only accepts keyword arguments - calling api with dynamic input

Tags: boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a function "get_metrics" that takes input which I want to build dynamically and pass it as parameter to function. But when call function with input I get error below. If I paste input directly in call it works.

raise TypeError(
TypeError: get_metric_data() only accepts keyword arguments.

```
def get_metrics(metrics_input):
    client = boto3.client(service_name='dms', region_name='us-east-1')
    response = client.get_metric_data(metrics_input)
    return response
```

metrics_input = **This is built dunamically**
result = get_metrics(metrics_input)

I tried directly adding generated input in api call and it works but does not work if passing as parameter to function.

Comment: What exactly is `metrics_input`?

Comment: MetricDataQueries=[{
 "Id": "identity1",
 "Label": "xxx",
 "MetricStat": {
  "Metric": {
   "Namespace": "AWS/DMS",
   "MetricName": "CPUUtilization",
   "Dimensions": [
    {
     "Name": "ReplicationInstanceIdentifier",
     "Value": "my-dms-instance"
    }
   ]
  },
  "Period": 3600,
  "Stat": "Maximum"
 }
},
],
        StartTime=2022-09-29 00:00:00,
        EndTime=2022-09-30 00:00:00,
ScanBy="TimestampAscending"

Comment: This is generated input and it works if I paste directly in call but does not work as a parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using json.loads(metrics_input) before passing it to function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can dynamically create the value of `metrics_input` as a dictionary:

```
metrics_input = {
    "MetricDataQueries":[{ "Id": "identity1", "Label": "xxx", "MetricStat": { "Metric": { "Namespace": "AWS/DMS", "MetricName": "CPUUtilization", "Dimensions": [ { "Name": "ReplicationInstanceIdentifier",     "Value": "my-dms-instance" } ] }, "Period": 3600, "Stat": "Maximum" } }, ], 
    "StartTime":"2022-09-29 00:00:00",
    "EndTime":"2022-09-30 00:00:00",
    "ScanBy": "TimestampAscending"
}
```

You can pass this value to boto3 using the double asterisk notation:

```
client.get_metric_data(**metrics_input)
```

This will automatically expand the dictionary into keyword arguments.